# Why does ASP.NET Windows Authentication work incorrectly on my test server?

Tags: c#, iis, active-directory, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication

My team is building a new internal ASP.NET MVC 5 app with Windows Authentication. When we need to retrieve the user's SID we do so like this:

```
public BaseController : Controller
{
    protected SecurityIdentifier GetSid()
    {
        var wi = (WindowsIdentity)this.User.Identity; 
        SecurityIdentifier sid = wi.Owner;
        return sid;
    }
}
```

On our local dev machines this works perfectly. We are able to retrieve the user's SID, store it, and (later) use the SID to query Active Directory for user information. (To be clear, running the site on one developer's machine and accessing it from another dev's machine still works as expected.) These are Windows 7 laptops running the site under IIS (not Express).

The site is also deployed to a test server. The test server is running Windows Server 2008 R2 and (again) the site is running under IIS. When accessing the test site the user is recognized through Windows Auth and is not required to log in. However, retrieving the user SID via the method above returns the *exact same SID* for each and every user.

Potentially useful info:

- `this.Identity.User.Name` *is* the correct username for each user.
- The "master" SID looks like "S-1-2-54-632". (I doubt that a SID is a sensitive number, but I changed the last 6 digits to be safe.)
- The real user SIDs have over 30 digits

This one SID is much shorter than the user SIDs retrieved on the dev machines. Further, when we attempt to query Active Directory for the user associated with this SID no user is found. Barring any other explanation I have assumed that this has something to do with the IIS (or perhaps AD) settings on the test server. I have limited experience with IIS configuration and virtually zero with AD. Regardless, I've tried tweaking a few settings for the site in IIS but the results are still the same. What could cause the test server to behave differently in this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `SecurityIdentifier sid = wi.User;` instead of `SecurityIdentifier sid = wi.Owner;` User is also a window object that has his owner - another user or group. So, on your test server probably you are receiving SID of group that owns current user object.